# Appending to agrument object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

The arguments variable returns an object like:

```
console.log(arguments)
=> { '0': 'arg1', '1': function[] }
```

What if I wanted to append to that and shift everything to the right?

```
{ '0': 'add', '1': 'arg1', '2': function[] }
```

How can I achieve this? Manually or with underscoreJS

Useful info with underscore:

> oArray_.toArray(list)
>
> Creates a real Array from the list (anything
>   that can be iterated over). Useful for transmuting the arguments
>   object.

Did something like:

```
var args = _.toArray(arguments)
args.unshift(fn)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply the [Array `unshift` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) on the `arguments` object:

```
Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, "add");
```

However, it's better not to mess with the `arguments` object. Rather convert it to an array, prepend `"add"` to that, and use it instead of `arguments` in your function body:

```
var args = ["add"].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
var args = ["add"].concat(_.toArray(arguments));
```

Comment: I guess it works even when using `object.apply`. Can accept in 8min

Comment: If it's for a small helper function, this might be acceptable (and it's quite concise). However, I'd recommend to test performance of both versions, there might be [serious de-optimisations](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments) going on.

Comment: This is actually going to be a method on a realtime MMORPG. I'll test performance. I used the 2nd example.

Comment: underscorejs actually has a `_.toArray` for arguments

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` object isn't a real array. It's a JS thing. Convert it to an array first.